# Force all URLs to be absolute

Tags: navigation

I have installed the following modules:

- Pathologic
- Advanced Aggregation

I implemented `hook_link_alter()` where I set `$variables['options']['absolute'] = TRUE;`.

This helped with fixing:

1. All links within text formats using input filter
2. Javascript and CSS file paths
3. Menu link paths

However, this does not help with Image Style paths or custom text generated by the Views module.

Is there a way to do this on a global basis instead of chasing down every single link generation method and altering it?

I also looked into an [Existing issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/744/force-all-links-to-be-absolute), but unfortunately it didn't help.